# How to have helpers in Hogan.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache, hogan.js

I am planning to use Hogan.js for my next project. I was trying to experiment with it a bit. I am just stuck and unable to find out how to use helpers with Hogan.js. I used to use to with Handlebars earlier. Is there a way to have a similar thing on Hogan?

Comment: lambda's is all you get, for me thats enough. do you have a specific problem you cant solve with lambda's?

Answer (score 2):

From [hogan.js official website](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/):

> Hogan.js was developed against the mustache test suite, so everything that holds true for templates as specified here, is also the case for hogan.js.

Check out the [mustache manpage](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) for a thorough explanation of features. Especially the part on lambda expressions.

The following is an example comparison of implementation between hogan.js and handlebars.js.

**Template**

```
{{#bold}}
    Willy is awesome.
{{/bold}}
```

**Hogan.js**

```
{
    "bold": function() {
        return function(text, render) {
            return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
        }
    }
}
```

**Handlebars.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('bold', function(options) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(
        '<b>' + options.fn(this) + '</b>'
    );
});
```

**Output**

```
<b>Willy is awesome.</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time with this until I found [this Hogan issue on Lambdas](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/199)

It is not longer needed pass render to the helper.

**Template**

```
{{#foo}}
    Lets put this text in a html tag.
{{/foo}}
```

**Hogan.js**

```
"foo": function() {
    return function(text) {
        return "<p>" + text + "</p>"
    }
```

**Output**

```
<p>Lets put this text in a html tag.</p>
```

My problem was a little bit harder since I had:

**Template**

```
{{#foo}}
    {{bar}}
{{/foo}}
```

So the `text` being passed to the helper was just `"{{bar}}"`
**Hogan.js**

```
"foo": function() {
    return function(text) {
// First get the rendered bar variable
        var bar = Hogan.compile(text).render(this));
        return "<p>" + bar + "</p>"
    }
```